# How to configure my Asus GT-AX11000 router to source all DNS queries from my pihole?

Tags: router, asus, pihole

I want my home LAN to direct all DNS queries to my pihole by configuring my Asus GT-AX11000 router to use my pihole machine as the sole DNS.  I tried following https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1046062/, but when I set my WAN DNS to my pihole's IP, I can't hit anything on the internet.  Settings in:  WAN --> WAN DNS Setting --> Assign --> Manual Setting.

I also tried setting my LAN --> DHCP Server --> DNS and WINS Server Setting -->  DNS Server 1, DNS Server 2, WINS Server.  I set all of these to my pihole's IP, but that doesn't seem to do anything, i.e. I don't see any queries in the pihole dashboard.
I also set "Advertise router's IP in addition to user-specified DNS = No", fwiw.

I jsut switched form an old netgear 6800 where the pihole worked brilliantly, so I'm skeptical that it is the problem here, but I'm not sure how to fully verify it.

Device versions and info:

```
Asus GT-AX11000 - Operation Mode:Wireless router Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.388_24328
Pi-hole version is v5.17.3 (Latest: v5.17.3)
  web version is v5.21 (Latest: v5.21)
  FTL version is v5.25.1 (Latest: v5.25.1)
```

Comment: Asus GT-AX11000 cannot run PiHole, you can point the Asus GT-AX11000 to another device that is running PiHole, and it should be as simple as setting the DNS provider to your PiHole device

Comment: @Ramhound - I apparently worded this poorly.  I'm not trying to install pihole on my asus router, I'm trying to configure my asus router to source all DNS queries from my pihole machine.  updated description to clarify better.

Comment: You're not setting it in the right place. That's for the *router* to get its queries. You need to set it for the LAN This is from a simulator for a different model but its close enough https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVOOE.png Setting the DNS server there should give your clients that DNS via DHCP - put your pihole address under *that*

Comment: ALso once its set, ipconfig /flushdns on the windows side, and renew your IP, and post the ipconfig output please to confirm